# how to build this function type wise on DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i have one problem :

i have 3-4 type element like label , textbox ,... and this element have 10-12 function . now **how to build this function type wise on DOM Element ?**

then i use this type code :

```
$('ElementID') . functionName();
```

then automatically call function type wise.

see in Detail :

Step :

1 . To make Dom element and then build my function on this DOM Element by type wise .

2 . Then i access this DOM Element like $('# DOM Element ID') and then i call my methods.

ex :
   if DOM Element type label then build to label all (10-12 function) functions .
            if  DOM Element type textbox then build to textbox all (10-12 function) functions .

3.then use any js file.

(note : you are not understand my problem then again ask ...)

Code  :

```
var Label1 = {

        GetHtml: function(id) {

            return $('<div id="'+id+'" class="drag LABLE" type="Label1"></div>');

        },

        _SetFont_family : function(CSS) {
            console.log(CSS);
        },
};
```

var Label2 = {

```
        GetHtml: function(id) {

            return $('<div id="'+id+'" class="drag LABLE" type="Label2"></div>');

        },

        _SetFont_family : function(CSS) {
            console.log(CSS);
        },
};
var ElementObject  = {
        LABLE1 : LABLE1 ,
LABLE2:LABLE2  
};
```

Call :

```
ElementObject[currentDOM.attr('type')]._SetFont_family(CSS);
```

then i selected element type is Label2 then call Label2 function and Label1 then call Label1's function.

so **give better idea** of this type flow in jquery or JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: i use so many dom element and every elelment have some type like label1 , lable2 ,... then i have type wise 10-12 function which this all function use dom element. so 1st i check element type and then apply it . so i plan to make jquery function and when i create this dom that time i build all functions by type .... so next time i easy to access this dom with dom function ...

Answer (score 0):

After accessing the element check it dom type.

For example:

1. access:

   `var $node = $('#element');`
2. get node name:

   ```
   var node_name = $node.get(0).nodeName;
   // or
   var node_name = $node[0].nodeName; // output: LABEL, INPUT etc
   ```
3. If node name is `INPUT` then you can check the type by:

   ```
   var node_type = $node[0].type;
   ```

---

***An example code:***

```
var $node = $('#input');
var node_name = $node[0].nodeName;
var node_type = null;
alert(node_name);

if( node_name == 'INPUT') {
    node_type = $node[0].type;
    alert( node_type );
}
```

***[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jJ5TR/2/)***

Comment: i use so many dom element and every elelment have some type like label1 , lable2 ,... then i have type wise 10-12 function which this all function use dom element. so 1st i check element type and then apply it . so i plan to make jquery function and when i create this dom that time i build all functions by type .... so next time i easy to access this dom with dom function ...

Comment: Repeating the same comment you wrote above doesn't make it any more understandable. "label1", "label2" aren't Javascript types. Do you mean classes or IDs? "type wise 10-12 function" is not understandable English (sorry if English isn't your native language).

Comment: "label1", "label2" is my type . and also 10-12 diff -diff type . and each have 10 -12 function .